How to win "attack on sub-station" in Emergency?
The shift is: There're 6 criminals, two bomb with about 30s left and two electrical hazards (one already red). The bombs, generators and the electricity switch(!) is blocked by the gate. During rain, even engineers usually die due to electricity damage before opening the gate.

So far, I've succeeded managing it once by abandoning all other emergencies, so that I lost the shift due to that and twice by using a verticopter for the criminals.
My usual approach is to send two SWAT and two engineers. The engineers need to open a gate before they can turn off the electricity. The engineers usually die long before completing the first job, opening the gate. This than leads to the bombs exploding and the electricity killing the SWAT officers which leaves me which 4 slots blocked.
Is there any more reliable way?

I was able to repeatedly win this event by freeing 4 slots immediately (so far I encountered nothing more important) and sending two SWAT units and two engineers. You cannot wait for the slot to become available, you need to force free them by sending 4 units home the second the event pops up.
The SWAT units need to engage first so that the engineers do not take damage. They need to open the gate, then one disables the electricity, while the other already starts with the first bomb (the southern one that turned yellow first) and the other joins when the electricity is off. They immediately need to disarm the second bomb, there's no room for errors.
If you missed sending in the SWAT teams first, the engineers need to leave the damage radius of the gun fight, otherwise they'll take too much damage. This however probably messes up the tiny time window, so the you might disarm the first bomb, but not the second in this case.

First, try to group the SWAT officers together and have them move as a team. This will make them more effective in dealing with the criminals.
Second, use your engineers strategically. Instead of sending them in first, have them wait near the gate until it's time to open it. This will allow them to provide cover for the SWAT officers as they approach the gate.
Third, consider using your medics to heal the SWAT officers as they move through the map. This will help them survive long enough to complete their objectives.

Good tips, thank you. The main issue are the bombs, the engineers need to get to the gate as quickly as possible while the swat team is still in action because otherwise the bombs cause a fire which harms the swat officer to losing their heals within seconds which can then no longer protect the engineers to that they can no longer furn off the electricity which then makes all further interventions impossible.

Does it work? If so, please click the checkmark. If not, I'll edit it.

Is it OK now or do u still need more time?

There's no healing of unit while they move afaik. I always use SWAT officers in groups. 2  SWAT vehicles are necessary to protect the engineers which cannot wait for the gun fight to be over, but they're covered. That's pretty much the strategy I always use for this emergency. And I loose about 90% of shifts with this emergency in it.
